# Como atualizar repositório Github depois de ter alterado arquivos localmente no Git?

Tags: git, github

Depois de ter criado um repositório no Github e enviados alguns arquivos para esse repositório, precisei fazer algumas alterações no arquivo, fiz os *commits*, mas não sei como enviar essas alteração para o Github.

Como eu faço isso?

Comment: Essa até eu que sou super tapado com Git sei responder. Basta fazer um `git push origin <branch>`, sendo *<branch>* o branch (duh) alvo. Dependendo da configuração, **origin** pode ser outro nome que você tenha definido.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Me parece que o seu problema é bem simples, só precisa saber o comando certo para enviar que é o [`push`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push):

```
git push
```

Tem inúmeras variações mas ele sozinho resolve o básico. Claro que o `commit` precisa estar correto para funcionar corretamente e seu repositório local também precisa estar corretamente configurado para trabalhar com o Github.

[Documentação do **Github**](https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote/).

Se a conexão com o Github ainda não foi estabelecida pode fazer isto (na primeira vez):

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:usuario/nomerepositorio.git
```

A não ser que tenha criado o repositório local com `git clone` aí só é necessário (na primeira vez):

```
git push origin master
```

Fonte: [resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10573992/221800).

Veja um diagrama que o [Oliver Steele](http://blog.osteele.com/posts/2008/05/my-git-workflow/) criou:

[image: fluxo de comandos Git]

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Vale dizer também que, normalmente, quando alguém cria um repo novo no GitHub escolhe a opção "adicionar README.md", isso significa que antes do push, será necessário um git pull para atualizar o repositório.